# Fading between scenes in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, android

I'm developing a game for Android and I'm using this code to fade between two scenes using a button:

```
 public class fading : MonoBehaviour {

        public Texture2D fadeOutTexture;
        public float fadeSpeed = 0.8f; 

        private int drawDepth = -1000; 
        private float alpha = 1.0f; 
        private int fadeDir = -1; 


        void onGUI () {

            alpha += fadeDir * fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(alpha);
            GUI.color = new Color (GUI.color.g, GUI.color.b, alpha);
            GUI.depth = drawDepth; 
            GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), fadeOutTexture); }

        public float BeginFade (int direction) {
            fadeDir = direction;
            return (fadeSpeed); }

        void onLevelWasLoaded() {
            BeginFade (-1);

        }
    }
```

Code attached to the UI button:

```
public void gameScene2() {
        float fadeTime = GameObject.Find ("scene2Choose").GetComponent<fading>().BeginFade(1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(fadeTime);
        Application.LoadLevel("gameScene2");
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:
ArgumentException: method return type is incompatible

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a `Coroutine` in order for above to work. For e.g

```
IEnumerator gameScene2() {
    float fadeTime = GameObject.Find ("scene2Choose").GetComponent<fading>().BeginFade(1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(fadeTime);
    Application.LoadLevel("gameScene2");
}
```

and in your `Button click` write like below
    `StartCoroutine(gameScene2());`

Comment: I've added the code above, thanks. When you say button click, do you mean the On Click() in the inspector? I cant see a StartCouroutine option. I've read that I need to put the StartCorotine in the Update method, so how to I link the button I am using to this?

Comment: You can try this : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/777818/46-ui-calling-function-on-button-click-via-script.html